# ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([555, 3])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([2, 3, 320, 320]))

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, data-mining

```py
def train_loop(dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    model.train()
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        # Move data to the same device as the model
        X = X.to(device)
        y = y.to(device)

        # Compute prediction and loss
        pred = model(X)

        pred = F.interpolate(pred, size=(320, 320), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)

        # Backpropagation
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        if batch % 100 == 0:
            loss, current = loss.item(), (batch + 1) * len(X)
            print(f"loss: {loss:>7f}  [{current:>5d}/{size:>5d}]")
```

```py
 loss_fn = torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=1e-5)

    epochs = 5
    for t in range(epochs):
        start_time = time.time()
        print(f"Epoch {t + 1}\n-------------------------------")
        train_loop(train_dataloader, model, loss_fn, optimizer, device)
        #test_loop(test_dataloader, model, loss_fn, device)
    end_time = time.time()
```

How to deal with this error? The target size is labeled with contain [x,y,label] of 555 and [label classes=3] and the input image is RGB that's why is 3.

I don't know if I need to reshape the label size.

Comment: Please share the entire error backtrace and not just the error message itself

Comment: Please sign in as "heb gs" so you can add your feedback to the answer from linpingta. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You meet this error because size of pred and y is different.

```
        pred = F.interpolate(pred, size=(320, 320), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)
```

pred size is (2,3,320,320), however, as y is (555,..), torch doesn't know how to calculate loss (BCEWithLogitsLoss) for it.

You may change size of pred same as y. As y is label with 3 classes (so it's multi class problem), you may check your model output.
I think your model output is strange because you do F.interpolate after that, which means your model output looks like a image..

Please check your model first so that it satisfies your task.